# How to Check If A Row Is In Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I’m looking to create a program that checks if data from one row is in two different tables already, and fails if it finds them so it doesn’t create duplicate rows in a table.

Currently I have

```
If NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_a)
```

Which works to stop it from duplicating rows in table a, but I want it to not be able to insert a row if the data is also already in table b. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can check a number of tables with a condition kind of `NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_a WHERE ..) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_b WHERE ..)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use NOT EXISTS with union all also.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(
SELECT 1 FROM Table_a WHERE condition
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 FROM Table_b WHERE condition
.
.
.
)
BEGIN
-- Your logic 
END
```